# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host

Tags: postgresql, patroni

Ok before this gets flag as duplicate, bear with me.

I'm trying to connect two replicas (.12 & .13) to a primary PGSQL13 DB (.11) in a lab environment using *synchronous stream replication* but it fails with the following log entries in the primary psql logs:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "192.168.23.11", user "replicator", SSL off
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "192.168.23.12", user "replicator", SSL off
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "192.168.23.13", user "replicator", SSL off
```

Here is the relevant pg_hba.conf entry on all servers:

```
host    all             all             192.168.23.0/28         md5
```

Changing to `scram-sha-256` or `trust` doesn't change anything. What am I missing here??

I'm on PGSQL13 and using patroni to bootstrap it. Replication used to work fine before I tested shutting down all servers and starting them back up. I'm thinking this command `SET password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256';` broke something but I thought pg_hba was validated before password was, and md5/scram-sha-256 should take care of that anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replication` without quotes is not the actual name of a database, it is a magic word. It does not match against `all`. You could list `all,replication` to cover both in the same line.